# strtol not behaving as expected, c

Tags: c, string, int, strtol

```
#include<limits.h>
#include<errno.h>

long output;

errno = 0;
output = strtol(input,NULL,10);
printf("long max = %ld\n",LONG_MAX);
printf("input = %s\n",input);
printf("output = %ld\n",output);
printf("direct call = %ld\n",strtol(input,NULL,10));
if(errno || output >= INT_MAX || output <= INT_MIN) {
    printf("Input was out of range of int, INT_MIN = %d, INT_MAX = %d\n",INT_MIN,INT_MAX);
    printf("Please input an integer within the allowed range:\n");
}
```

when the code above is fed with an input array of {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1'}

i get an output of:

```
long max = 9223372036854775807
input = 12345678901
output = -539222987
direct call = 3755744309
```

what is going on... strtol appears to be suffering from overflow but not setting errno

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most likely not including the required `<stdio.h>` and/or `<stdlib.h>` headers.

Your code works fine (GCC in 64bit mode) once you include those:

```
$ cat t.c
#include<limits.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    long output;
    char input[] = "12345678901";
    errno = 0;
    output = strtol(input,NULL,10);
    printf("long max = %ld\n",LONG_MAX);
    printf("input = %s\n",input);
    printf("output = %ld\n",output);
    printf("direct call = %ld\n",strtol(input,NULL,10));
    if(errno || output >= INT_MAX || output <= INT_MIN) {
        printf("Input was out of range of int, INT_MIN = %d, INT_MAX = %d\n",INT_MIN,INT_MAX);
        printf("Please input an integer within the allowed range:\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic t.c
$ ./a.out
long max = 9223372036854775807
input = 12345678901
output = 12345678901
direct call = 12345678901
Input was out of range of int, INT_MIN = -2147483648, INT_MAX = 2147483647
Please input an integer within the allowed range:
```

BTW, you should be saving `errno` right after the `strtol` call, the library functions you call between `strtol` and your conditional could alter its value.

Comment: thanks, that solved it!  I had stdio but not stdlib, wasn't aware it was needed here. Thanks for pointing out the errno problem.

Comment: @user1019856, your compiler most probably would have told you if you'd compile your code with all warnings on, `-Wall` or so.